# XCode Distribution Certificate valid in provisioning portal, Organiser and Keychain but not in code signing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, certificate, distribution, provisioning

As the title says, the distribution certificate showing as valid in the keychain, the provisioning portal and in Organiser. However in Code signing I see "iPhone Distribution:my name" under "identities without provisioning profile" or "no profiles currently match" when auto is set.

I've revoked my developer and distribution certificates twice, and requested and received new ones (following stackoverflow and Apple guides) via Xcode but I can't go through to distribution without receiving an error. 
Any help would be very much appreciated
Thanks, Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created a provisioning profile using the certificate and the apps app id?

Comment: Thanks drekka. I had a developer certificate, distribution certificate, and developer provisioning profile but I didn't have distribution provisioning profile.